# TortoiseHG: Only pull selected changesets?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have 2 repositories A and B. I make 5 changes to A, but only 2 of them should also appear in B. So this is what I tried:

1. Pushed the 5 changes to repo A
2. Changed the path of repo B to that of repo A
3. Clicked the "Check for incoming changesets" button for repo B

Now I see the 5 changes I made for repo A. This is where I am stuck, how can I only get 2 of the 5 changesets now? I tried "Pull to here", but this does not work in my case, it gets all changesets below the one I selected.

How can I get for example the first and third changeset from the list? Possible at all?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

When you pull changesets between repositories you cannot skip changesets in between. If a changeset has  different parents in two repositories, it is not the same changeset.

You can accomplish what you are after by exporting [patches](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/patches.html) of the changesets you want and then import them into the other repository. That way, you have the changes you want from repo A in B, but the changesets will not have the same [nodeid](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/Nodeid) in the two repositories.

Comment: The transplant extension can help with this.

Comment: @SteveKaye `transplant` moves changesets between branches in the same repository, not two different ones.

Comment: No, that is not correct.  The in-built `graft` command does that, the [`transplant`](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension) extension can move them between repositories but doesn't have the smarter merging abilities of `graft`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like A and B were clones of the same repository.  If that is the case, branching is probably what you need.  If you have a history where `A` contains:

```
C:\example>hg glog --template "rev{rev}:{desc}\r\n"
@  rev6:change7
|
o  rev5:change6
|
o  rev4:change5
|
o  rev3:change4
|
o  rev2:change3
|
o  rev1:change2
|
o  rev0:change1
```

If your `B` was originally just `rev0` and `rev1` and you wanted `rev3` and `rev5` added to it, you can just update to `rev1` and graft `rev3` and `rev5` onto it:

```
C:\example>hg update 1
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 5 files removed, 0 files unresolved

C:\example>hg glog --template "rev{rev}:{desc}\r\n"
o  rev6:change7
|
o  rev5:change6
|
o  rev4:change5
|
o  rev3:change4
|
o  rev2:change3
|
@  rev1:change2
|
o  rev0:change1

C:\example>hg graft 3 5
grafting revision 3
grafting revision 5

C:\example>hg glog --template "rev{rev}:{desc}\r\n"

@  rev8:change6      <--- contains change 1, 2, 4, 6
|
o  rev7:change4
|
| o  rev6:change7    <--- contains changes 1-7.
| |
| o  rev5:change6
| |
| o  rev4:change5
| |
| o  rev3:change4
| |
| o  rev2:change3
|/
o  rev1:change2
|
o  rev0:change1
```

To avoid duplication of changesets and a little pre-planning, the changes that need to be on both `A` and `B` branches can be checked into `B` and merged into `A`, whereas changesets that only belong on A can be directly checked into A:

```
C:\example>hg glog --template "rev{rev}:{branch}:{desc}\r\n"

@  rev8:A:change7     <--- contains changes 1-7.
|
o    rev7:A:Merge
|\
| o  rev6:B:change6   <--- contains change 1, 2, 4, 6
| |
o |  rev5:A:change5
| |
o |  rev4:A:Merge
|\|
| o  rev3:B:change4
| |
o |  rev2:A:change3
|/
o  rev1:default:change2
|
o  rev0:default:change1
```